# quasi random set and multivariate normal distribution matlab

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, random, normal-distribution

I have a multivariate normal distribution generated using `mvnrnd`.

I would like to generate this multivariate normal distribution not in a pure random way, but using for example a SOBOL sequence and I don't know how to implement it in Matlab. I know how to create a qrandstream but not how to use it in order to generate a multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think about the answer and this is my proposal:

R = chol(Correlation_Matrix) % I apply the Cholesky decomposition to the correlation matrix

Sobol = sobolset(1) % generate the sobolset with dimension 1

Sobolnumbers = net(Sobol,100) % take the firs 100 numbers of the sequence

Z = norminv(Sobolnumbers,0,1) % take the Z normal standardize values using norminv

X = mu + Z*R % obtain X pseudo random numbers from a multivariate normal distribution

Answer (score 1):

A multidimensional Sobol set is required accordingly. Please see this [function](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58669-q-mvnrnd-target-) for implementation

Comment: Besides taking the provided Sobol set, your code also depends on `particles(idx) = rand(nnz(idx),1);`, where rand() implies to be another source of randomness. With this extra `rand()`, how the only Sobol-sourced randomness could be preserved?